# Mathematical induction: propper use of assumption?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Let $u_n$ be any recursive expression containing $u_{n-2}$. We are trying to prove that $u_n= f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is any well defined and not recursive expression of $n$.

Let's assume we know $u_1=f(1)$ and therefore we assume that $u_k = f(k)$. We now must prove that

$u_{k+1}=f(k+1)$ to conclude our induction. Because $u_{n-2}$ appears in the recursive definition of $u_n$, it's clear that $u_{k-1}$ will appear on $u_{k+1}$.

My question is: my hypothesis is only about $u_k$, but can't I apply it to $u_{k-1}$?

For example, if the case where that my hypothesis is $u_k=2^k$, can I conclude that $u_{k-1}=2^{k-1}$ when I'm trying to prove that $u_{k+1}=2^{k+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

An explicit example would help, but I will write what I think you mean. To proceed with any induction proof, you have to determine the *dependence* of each case on the ones preceding it. So, if you are trying to prove that a certain relation holds for a certain $n$, you have to determine how many cases that precede it must hold in order to be able to deduce that it holds for $n$. Based on this, you can distinguish separate cases:

$(1)$ If it is possible to deduce the case $n$ only from $n-1$, then you only need to prove the case $n=1$ and this is the usual form of induction.

$(2)$ If, in order to deduce the case $n$, you need the preceding $m<n$ relations, you have to prove each case $m\ge i \ge1$ separately then proceed with the inductive step, namely, "Suppose the relation holds for the cases $n-1, n-2,....n-m$, we can prove that it holds for $n$ as follows....". Now your question lacks details so I can't fully apply this, but here are my thoughts, If you can prove the relation for $n=1$ but seem to need the preceding two cases to prove the case $n$, then you can do one of two things; either prove the relation for $n=0$ and proceed, or prove it for $n=2$ independently of $n=1$ and proceed, If you can't prove either, then there is no way to prove this by induction since you can't even prove it for the case $2$ or $3$ (depending on whether you will prove $n=0$ or $n=2$.)

Of course, these are not all the possibilities, for example, you may be able to prove $n$ using the case $n-2$, if so, you can proceed by induction for odd and even values of $n$ separately while keeping in mind that the relation may not hold for one of them, but the general idea is that you have to determine *how many* cases you need in order prove the one after them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to consider, depending on the particular situation. Here are some details, and basic examples, of the ones I can think of.

**Case: $1$**

One possibility is that $u_n$ is defined *only* for odd $n$, with $u_n$ for even values of $n$ being unspecified or unknown, and in particular not of a concern in the situation. For example, you may have $u_1 = 2$ and

$$u_{n} = 4u_{n-2}, \; \forall \; n = 2k + 1, \; k \ge 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

In this case, assume your hypothesis is that

$$f(n) = 2^{n}, \; \forall \; n = 2k - 1, \; k \ge 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You then have $f(1) = 2^{1} = 2 = u_1$ as the base case, and you can use induction in steps of $2$ to prove your hypothesis.

**Case: $2$**

In this case, assume $u_n$ is defined for all $n \ge 1$. For this, as a base case, you will *have* to know $u_2$ fits whatever your hypothesis is. In addition, you will need to use something like [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) in all $3$ sub-cases.

**Case: $2$A**

There's one basic function which can handle both the odd & even indices $n$ in $u_n$. For example, extending \eqref{eq1A}, assume you have $u_2 = 4$ and

$$u_{n} = 4u_{n-2}, \; \forall \; n \ge 3 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Your hypothesis would be an extension of \eqref{eq2A},

$$f(n) = 2^{n}, \; \forall \; n \ge 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

You now have $2$ base cases to check, i.e., $f(1)$, as done earlier in case $1$, plus $f(2) = 2^2 = 4 = u_{2}$. Now, with strong induction, you assume \eqref{eq4A} is true for *all* $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 2$ and then prove it's true for $n = k + 1$.

**Case: $2$B**

In this case, the odd and even indices of $u_n$ have different behavior due to $u_2$ having an initial value which doesn't match the general case of extending the odd values. For example, reuse \eqref{eq3A} but assume $u_2 = 3$ instead. In this case, your would be an adapted version of \eqref{eq4A}, i.e.,

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
2^{n}, & n = 2k - 1, \; k \ge 1 \\
3(2^{n-2}), & n = 2k, \; k \ge 1
\end{cases}
\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Here, the base cases are $f(1) = 2^{1} = 2 = u_1$ works as shown before, and with $f(2) = 3(2^{2-2}) = 3 = u_2$. For the inductive phase, where you assume \eqref{eq5A} holds for all $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 2$, you will need to handle the case of $n = k + 1$ by checking whether $n$ is even or odd and handling these $2$ parity options somewhat separately.

**Case: $2$C**

In this sub-case, the definition $u_n$ has sub-parts, so its behavior for odd and even indices are different. For example, assume you have

$$u_n =
\begin{cases}
4u_{n-2}, & n = 2k + 1, \; k \ge 1 \\
9u_{n-2}, & n = 2k + 2, \; k \ge 1
\end{cases}
\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Assume $u_2 = 3$ again as in case $2$B. However, $f(n)$ is now defined as

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
2^{n}, & n = 2k - 1, \; k \ge 1 \\
3^{n-1}, & n = 2k, \; k \ge 1
\end{cases}
\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

The base cases are $f(1) = 2^{1} = 2 = u_{1}$ and $f(2) = 3^{2-1} = 3 = u_{2}$, as before. Also, as in case $2$B, for the inductive phase, where you assume \eqref{eq7A} holds for all $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 2$, you will need to handle the case of $n = k + 1$ by checking whether $n$ is even or odd and handling these $2$ parity cases somewhat separately.

---

The above case examples are relatively simple, with most situations you encounter usually being  more complex. Nonetheless, the basic principles outlined above will still hold in those situations.